# unique rows with COUNT and a BLOB column - DB2

Tags: sql, count, db2, blob, distinct

I have one BLOB column that I want to select at the same time as some other column and a COUNT of the number of associated rows in another table.  Here's what I have:

```
SELECT locations.id, locations.name, photo,
    COUNT(items.id) OVER (PARTITION BY locations.id) AS num_items
FROM locations
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON locations.id = items.location_id
ORDER BY locations.name ASC
```

`photo` is the BLOB column.  This query gets all the data I want, but I see *x* rows for each `location`, where *x* is the number of `item` rows associated with that `location`.

So I'm getting:

```
id          name          photo          num_items
1           location1                    3
1           location1                    3
1           location1                    3
2           location2                    1
3           location3                    2
3           location3                    2
4           location4                    0
```

What I want:

```
id          name          photo          num_items
1           location1                    3
2           location2                    1
3           location3                    2
4           location4                    0
```

The problem is that you can't do `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, or `MIN` on a `BLOB` column.

Answer (score 1):

I always seem to figure out the answer right after posting on here.  :P

```
SELECT location_data.*, photo
FROM (
    SELECT locations.id, locations.name, COUNT(DISTINCT items.id) AS num_items
    FROM locations
    LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON locations.id = items.location_id
    GROUP BY locations.id, locations.name
) location_data
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT locations.id, photo
    FROM locations
) photo_data ON location_data.id = photo_data.id
ORDER BY name ASC
```